# Unable to fetch data from Presto SQL (Trino) using pySpark

Tags: ssl, pyspark, aws-glue, trino, presto-jdbc

I have a pyspark job that I run on AWS Glue.
The code is running fine when I run it through my local Machine.
But when I try to run the same code from AWS Glue I am not able to fetch data.
Below is my code and error message.
From the output you will notice that I am able to get schema information. Error happens as soon as I try to get the data.

Update :
The issue is happening as the worker node are not able to access the Keystore present in the Master node. Can someone help how to copy the file to child node or how to make the file accessible to the child nodes?

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import boto3
import ssl
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType


## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
sqlCont = SQLContext(spark)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)


query = "SELECT * FROM test.employee where id='1001'"

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

s3_client.download_file('bucket1', 'rootca_ca.jks', '/tmp/rootca_ca.jks')
  

conparms_r = glueContext.extract_jdbc_conf("presto_test", catalog_id = None)
 
source_df = sqlCont.read.format("jdbc").option("driver","io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoDriver").option("url", "jdbc:presto://test-db.net:18000/hive").option("query", query).option("user", conparms_r['user']).option("password", conparms_r['password']).option("SSL", True).option("SSLKeyStorePath","/tmp/rootca_ca.jks").option("SSLKeyStorePassword","test12").load()



print("************************************source_df SUCCESSFULLY CREATED !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*****************************************")

source_df.printSchema()
   
source_df.show(5)
```

Output:

```
************************************source_df SUCCESSFULLY CREATED !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*****************************************
root
 |-- lineage_key: long (nullable = true)
 |-- agreement_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- termination_date: timestamp (nullable = true)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pytest", line 51, in <module>
    source_df.show(5)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 378, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o91.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 100.64.188.253, executor 1): java.sql.SQLException: Error setting up SSL: /tmp/rootca_ca.jks (No such file or directory)
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoDriverUri.setupClient(PrestoDriverUri.java:235)
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoDriver.connect(PrestoDriver.java:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.prestosql.jdbc.$internal.client.ClientException: Error setting up SSL: /tmp/rootca_ca.jks (No such file or directory)
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.$internal.client.OkHttpUtil.setupSsl(OkHttpUtil.java:241)
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoDriverUri.setupClient(PrestoDriverUri.java:203)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: The error complains about `/tmp/rootca_ca.jks` file. Do you have it?

Comment: Yes.. I checked the file is present.. i am able to get the schema.. issue is happening only when i try to get the data.

Comment: Does the file exists on all nodes (yarn nodes?) you run your spark job on?

Comment: I am running the script as a glue job. I did a file exists check at several points in the code and it does exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by passing the certificate location as job parameter --extra-files
and referring in the code as below:

```
 source_df = sqlCont.read.format("jdbc").option("driver","io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoDriver").option("url", "jdbc:presto://test-db.net:18000/hive").option("query", query).option("user", conparms_r['user']).option("password", conparms_r['password']).option("SSL", True).option("SSLKeyStorePath","./rootca_ca.jks").option("SSLKeyStorePassword","test12").load()
```